# Using the scroll wheel in Flash actionscript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript

When I am testing my Flash Actionscript 2 application in Flash, the scroll wheel doesn't work, but when I test the same application in the browser, the scroll wheel works. The code i'm using is very simple;

```
var mouseListener:Object = new Object();
mouseListener.onMouseWheel = function(delta) {
    songList_mc._y = songList_mc._y + (delta * 3);  
}
Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);
```

Is there a setting that i'm missing out which disabled the scroll wheel when testing in Flash?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mouseListener:Object = new Object();
mouseListener.onMouseWheel = function(delta)
{
    if ((delta > 0 && songList_mc._y < 1025) || (delta < 0 && songList_mc._y > 0))
    {
        songList_mc._y = songList_mc._y + (delta * 3);
    }
};
Mouse.addListener(mouseListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

The mouse wheel does not work in some flash wmode's